# Calling a google sheets custom function from another custom function

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying the following in a Google Sheet which produces an error because although `function_2()` **correctly returns an object** when I test it in the editor (or when I set it to return `JSON.stringify` and call it in the spreadsheet directly which displays correct JSON), **that object is somehow converted to an empty string when it should be passed to `function_1()` as a parameter**:

```
=function_1(B2,B3,function_2(A1,A2))
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Custom functions should return a single value or an array of values in order to work in a Google Sheets formulas.

The value or values should be valid Google Sheets values, in other words, number, text, boolean or date.

JavaScript objects types that are converted to valid Google Sheets are

- Number to number. Percentage, currency and other number formats depend on Google Sheets formatting.
- String to text.
- Date to date.

  - Note: Conversion to time, date-time or duration depends on cell formatting but duration could be complicated
- Boolean to boolean.

Reference

- [Custom functions in Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions)

Comment: Got it so since I'm returning a valid JS object but not a valid GS object it's not working. Thanks!